# Are muslims allowed to whatch cartoons or anime

Tags: halal-haram

I'm trying my best to be a loyal moslim and researched if the daily things I doe are haram. And have a better view because of this website. But I couldn't find anything on cartoons and anime that's why I ask of you to please help me find out if anime and cartoons are haram. Thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

sorry for my bad english :D

when Abu Hamid Al-Ghazali asked about songs he answered "its halal is halal and its haram is haram", he meant that if the song has a haram speech so it's haram, if not then it's halal

you can use this philosophy in your hole life, for example, and not as a limitation if the cartoon or anime has a haram scene then it's haram, if not then it's halal :)

I suggest you to watch "Bilal: A New Breed of Hero" cartoon movie